# putting a variable in an array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm new to php and I'm stuck with putting a variable in a an array

All i want to do is define a file location from a variable

looking and the code below my variable is **$requested_album**, i know what i have put in below is incorrect but i have ask multiple people and nothing seems to work!

Please help :)

```
  $uploader = new Uploader();
        $data = $uploader->upload($_FILES['files'], array(
            'limit' => 10, //Maximum Limit of files. {null, Number}
            'maxSize' => 10, //Maximum Size of files {null, Number(in MB's)}
            'extensions' => null, //Whitelist for file extension. {null, Array(ex: array('jpg', 'png'))}
            'required' => false, //Minimum one file is required for upload {Boolean}
            'uploadDir' => "../albums/$requested_album", //Upload directory {String}
            'title' => array('name'), //New file name {null, String, Array} *please read documentation in README.md
            'removeFiles' => true, //Enable file exclusion {Boolean(extra for jQuery.filer), String($_POST field name containing json data with file names)}
            'perms' => null, //Uploaded file permisions {null, Number}
            'onCheck' => null, //A callback function name to be called by checking a file for errors (must return an array) | ($file) | Callback
            'onError' => null, //A callback function name to be called if an error occured (must return an array) | ($errors, $file) | Callback
            'onSuccess' => null, //A callback function name to be called if all files were successfully uploaded | ($files, $metas) | Callback
            'onUpload' => null, //A callback function name to be called if all files were successfully uploaded (must return an array) | ($file) | Callback
            'onComplete' => null, //A callback function name to be called when upload is complete | ($file) | Callback
            'onRemove' => 'onFilesRemoveCallback' //A callback function name to be called by removing files (must return an array) | ($removed_files) | Callback
        ));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use below code. Its work for me.

```
$requested_album = "test";
$arr = array(
    'limit' => 10, //Maximum Limit of files. {null, Number}
    'maxSize' => 10, //Maximum Size of files {null, Number(in MB's)}
    'extensions' => null, //Whitelist for file extension. {null, Array(ex: array('jpg', 'png'))}
    'required' => false, //Minimum one file is required for upload {Boolean}
    'uploadDir' => "../albums/".$requested_album."/picture.jpg", //Upload directory {String}
    'title' => array('name'), //New file name {null, String, Array} *please read documentation in README.md
    'removeFiles' => true, //Enable file exclusion {Boolean(extra for jQuery.filer), String($_POST field name containing json data with file names)}
    'perms' => null, //Uploaded file permisions {null, Number}
    'onCheck' => null, //A callback function name to be called by checking a file for errors (must return an array) | ($file) | Callback
    'onError' => null, //A callback function name to be called if an error occured (must return an array) | ($errors, $file) | Callback
    'onSuccess' => null, //A callback function name to be called if all files were successfully uploaded | ($files, $metas) | Callback
    'onUpload' => null, //A callback function name to be called if all files were successfully uploaded (must return an array) | ($file) | Callback
    'onComplete' => null, //A callback function name to be called when upload is complete | ($file) | Callback
    'onRemove' => 'onFilesRemoveCallback' //A callback function name to be called by removing files (must return an array) | ($removed_files) | Callback
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [limit] => 10
    [maxSize] => 10
    [extensions] => 
    [required] => 
    [uploadDir] => ../albums/test/picture.jpg
    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
        )

    [removeFiles] => 1
    [perms] => 
    [onCheck] => 
    [onError] => 
    [onSuccess] => 
    [onUpload] => 
    [onComplete] => 
    [onRemove] => onFilesRemoveCallback
)
```

**Check Demo: [Click Here](https://eval.in/572509)**

Comment: reason for -1 plz?

Comment: wasn't me. The above doesn't work, its not seeing the variable, so the file will save in the albums forder

Comment: Thanks Ruchish! how do make it look like this albums/.$requested_album/picture.jpg - the requested_album is the folder

Comment: check edited code and please upvote and accept the answer. @JakeStow

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
                'limit' => 10, //Maximum Limit of files. {null, Number}
                'maxSize' => 10, //Maximum Size of files {null, Number(in MB's)}
                'extensions' => null, //Whitelist for file extension. {null, Array(ex: array('jpg', 'png'))}
                'required' => false, //Minimum one file is required for upload {Boolean}
                'uploadDir' => "../albums/".$requested_album, //Upload directory {String}
                'title' => array('name'), //New file name {null, String, Array} *please read documentation in README.md
                'removeFiles' => true, //Enable file exclusion {Boolean(extra for jQuery.filer), String($_POST field name containing json data with file names)}
                'perms' => null, //Uploaded file permisions {null, Number}
                'onCheck' => null, //A callback function name to be called by checking a file for errors (must return an array) | ($file) | Callback
                'onError' => null, //A callback function name to be called if an error occured (must return an array) | ($errors, $file) | Callback
                'onSuccess' => null, //A callback function name to be called if all files were successfully uploaded | ($files, $metas) | Callback
                'onUpload' => null, //A callback function name to be called if all files were successfully uploaded (must return an array) | ($file) | Callback
                'onComplete' => null, //A callback function name to be called when upload is complete | ($file) | Callback
                'onRemove' => 'onFilesRemoveCallback' //A callback function name to be called by removing files (must return an array) | ($removed_files) | Callback
            );
```

$uploader = new Uploader();

$data = $uploader->upload($_FILES['files'], $arr);

Try using this one.